# How can I test that a hidden element appears after click in React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a custom dropdown in my HTML that holds two elements. On click, the elements become visible and if I click either one it fires a function. The problem I'm having is the React testing library can't detect the hidden elements when I click the dropdown so my test fails. How can I write my tests so React Testing Library

1. After click detects my element?
2. After click and the element is visible test that my function fires?

Note that my test passed before I moved the element behind a dropdown.

```
test('expect that await getXMLDownload is called when Download XML is clicked', async () => {
  setup(props);

  const button = screen.queryByTestId('download-button');
  userEvent.click(button);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText('Download XML')).toBeInTheDocument(); // the test can't find it so it fails
  });

  const downloadXML = screen.getByText('Download XML');
  userEvent.click(downloadXML);

  expect(props.getXMLDownload).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

        <DropdownMenu
          trigger={(
            <Button
              data-testid="download-button"
              variant={ButtonVariant.secondary}
              style={{ textTransform: 'none' }}
            >
              <Icon
                size="large"
                icon={IconName.Download}
              />
            </Button>
          )}
        >
          <DropdownMenu.Item>
            <p
              onClick={() => initiateTxtDownload(
                `activity_report_${new Date()}`,
                generateTxtReport(reportData, agent, fraudTypesData),
              )}
            >
              Download Text
            </p>
          </DropdownMenu.Item>
          <DropdownMenu.Item>
            {sarReportV2 && (
              <p
                onClick={async () => initiateTxtDownload(
                  `activity_report_${new Date()}${caseToken}.xml`,
                  (await getXMLDownload(domainToken)).payload,
                )}
              >Download XML
              </p>
            )}
          </DropdownMenu.Item>
        </DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: *The problem I'm having is the React testing library can't detect the hidden elements when I click the dropdown so my test fails* - shouldn't the elements be visible when you click?

Comment: Exactly, and it is in the UI, but in the test it's not so it fails. I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm assuming there is some sort of timing issue so that's why I used async/await. I've also tried setTimeout and both fail.

Comment: It can be because of the new line symbol that you have after `Download XML` and before `</p>`

Comment: What new line symbol?

Comment: The one between `>Download XML` and `</p>`

Comment: You think because it's not all one line it's causing an issue?

Comment: For start - which version of `userEvent` are you using? As far as I rememeber from version 14 all APIs are async so you should await on click.